# Creating workbook and worksheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to load an existing Excel file and create a new sheet inside that workbook, but my code is not working using `openpyxl`.

```
rb = load_workbook("C:\Raw_Dump.xlsx")
rb.create_sheet("Sheet2")
sheet1 = rb.worksheets[0]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You have to `save` the workbook to the same filename:

```
rb.save(r"C:\Raw_Dump.xlsx")
```

full working example:

```
import openpyxl

ws_name = r"Raw_Dump.xlsx"
rb = openpyxl.load_workbook(ws_name)
rb.create_sheet("Sheet2")
rb.save(ws_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent a long time searching this and found the best way is to do sheet removal.  The code below worked for me:

```
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    if sheet not in "MY_SHEET_I_WANNA_KEEP":
        rm_sheet = wb[sheet];
        wb.remove_sheet(rm_sheet)
wb.save("JustOneSheet.xlsx")
```

Comment: `sheet not in "MY_SHEET_I_WANNA_KEEP"` performs a substring search. Probably not what you want here. For instance, it will keep sheets like `WANNA` and `SHEET` Besides the OP isn't asking for that.